# How does a computing system convert a voltage value into it's digital representation?

Tags: adc

I have recently done an undergraduate course in computer hardware ( cover's logic gates, flip flops, a little bit of LC-3 architecture etc. and C programming ), and there's this question I have that's been bugging me. How would a collection of logic gates ( in the case I mention, an ADC ) actually sample an analog wave at various points and convert these values into digital representations. To be precise, suppose I have a sine wave that varies between 0 to 10V in absolute amplitude, and I have sampled a value of 7V. How exactly would an arrangement of logic gates create the digital representation (0000111) from it ?

Comment: Both google and wikipedia seem to be working fine from where I am...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter

Answer (score 2):

An ADC works by comparing two voltages, the one that needs to be converted and a voltage from its internal DAC.

The comparison is done by successive approximation starting on the most significant bit all the way to the least significant bit.

For example:

Suppose we have an 8 bit ADC that has an input range from 0V to 5V.
In this case 0V would correspond to 00000000 (0x00) and 5V (actually 4.998046875V) would correspond to 11111111 (0xFF).

If we feed 3V to the ADC it would convert it in 8 steps

1. 10000000 -> 2.5V (Below input voltage, bit will remain set)
2. 11000000 -> 3.75V (Above input voltage, bit will be 0)
3. 10100000 -> 3.125V (Above input voltage, bit will be 0)
4. 10010000 -> 2.8125V (Below input voltage, bit will remain set)
5. 10011000 -> 2.96875V (Below input voltage, bit will remain set)
6. 10011100 -> 3.046875V (Above input voltage, bit will be 0)
7. 10011010 -> 3.0078125V (Above input voltage, bit will be 0)
8. 10011001 -> 2.98828125V (Below input voltage, bit will remain set)

The value returned by the ADC will be 10011001 (0xAA).

Comment: Some of your values use a period (x.xx) and some use a comma (x,xx).

Comment: @JYelton Just fixed it. Here in Portugal we use the comma as a decimal separator and I forgot to replace it we a period when I copied the value from the calculator.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make things consistent. :)

Answer (score 1):

All ADCs use comparators in some way, that is they compare two analog voltages and the output is a digital signal that tells which one is higher.

The most common ADCs in microcontrollers use successive approximation. That is, they use a DAC and compare the output to the sampled analog input voltage.  They start with the highest bit by using the voltage for 10...0 (half the reference voltage), then depending on the outcome use 010...0 or 110..0 and so on work their way down to the least significant bit.

Comment: so would the circuitry compare the voltage with every single possible sampling value ( all integers between 0 and 10 ) and depending on the result of the comparison, use something like a multiplexer to arrive at the desired (preset) digital representation ? I assume it would compare two voltage values by playing them off against each other and then detecting whether the resulting voltage is postive negative or zero.

Comment: No, there is one iteration for every bit.  Maybe the edit clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the simplest ADCs is the ramping ADC. It uses a DAC and compares its analogue output with the unknown analogue input with a comparator: -

[image]

A DAC can convert a digital number to an analogue voltage. The DAC is presented with a digital number that ramps from (say) 000h to 3FFh (this would be a 10-bit DAC). This can be arranged to produce an analogue voltage in the range 0 to 10.23V.

It will have an analogue voltage resolution of 10mV i.e. every single-bit increase in the digital number fed to it will increase the DAC output by 10mV. As 1023 = 3FFh you can possibly see that I've purposely made my DAC (in this example) work in lumps of 10mV to tie in with the question.

The "unknown" signal is compared using an analogue comparator to the ramping up DAC signal. The comparator has a digital output that remains low until the two inputted voltages cross over in amplitude then it remains high.

So, if you use a digital circuit to stop the ramp when the comparator output switches, you have found the amplitude of the unknown signal - it is the digital number presenting itself to the DAC.

There are other types of ADCs and most of them are quicker at "targetting" the real value of the analogue signal but the ramp method described above I think, is the simplest to understand.

Conceptually, the circuit shown above is the same as a successive approximation ADC - how "clever" does the MCU want to be at getting close to the unknown analogue - how can it use the comparator more efficiently? There are a few options of course.

Comment: Good explanation of the concept, but this is not the architecture that I know as an "integrating" ADC. See: http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/MT-027.pdf

Comment: @BPete I think you are quite correct. Tis late in the day for me so I'll rephrase my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just have resistor dividers at the inputs of comparators.

[image: Circuit diagram]

With 4 comparators, you have a 2-bit resolution (4 stages of voltage discretization). Throw that into a 4 to 2 decoder and you've got a 2 bit output of 00,01,10,11 for low to high voltage.

Comment: You have enough rep to inline that image.